# Create a lookup in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I Have an accounts table with account number and account name in a model called accounts

how do I create a lookup such that whenever I enter an account number in django template, account name get populated automatically

my models at attempt are

```
class Account(models.Model):
    account_number = models.IntegerField()
    account_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    bank_name = models.ForeignKey(Bank, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return account_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('accounts')


class AccountLookup(models.Model):
    account_number = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE):
    account_name = models. ???????????
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to show us your models.py file before we can answer.

Comment: Thanks, I have edit the question with my 2 models

Comment: Ok, what do you mean by "enter an account number then account name gets populated automatically"

Comment: so if i have account number which is 400 and name Sales. when I am in the template and i enter 400 i want sales to appear next to 400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something you can use in a template that will render account name starting from an AccountLookup object, then its

```
{{accountlookup_instance.account_number.account_name}}
```

Note that this will hit the DB again, unless you used `select_related()` on the queryset which obtained the AccountLookup object(s) in the first place.

Python code can likewise use this dotted path, with the same caveat.

You might regard it as a simplification to be able to refer to what looks like a field (but isn't). In which case you define it as a property

```
class AccountLookup(models.Model):
    account_number = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
    @property
    def account_name(self):
        return self.account_number.account_name
```

(It gets more useful if you need to apply some standard formatting to the account name to convert it into a more human-readable form in this context).

By the way, calling it account_number is confusing. Better to just name a ForeignKey field for what it is. `account` in this case: the account object linked by a ForeignKey to this object. Yes, it's represented internally by an `account_id` which is commonly an integer (the auto-generated primary key), but that's a low level detail Django programmers are not often concerned with.